# Bing Geocode API, SSIS, C# Script

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, bing-maps

I'm trying to replicate what I found here to use bing's geocode `API`: https://sqlmd.wordpress.com/2012/03/27/using-the-ssis-scripting-task-to-geocode-addresses/

When I run what I have I get this error:

> Error: 0xFFFFFFFF at Get Lat Long Bing, Error:: Could not find default
>   endpoint element that references contract
>   'bing.geocode.IGeocodeService' in the ServiceModel client
>   configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was
>   found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching
>   this contract could be found in the client element.

The script that I'm using is `C#`.

```
Public Sub Main()
    If Dts.Variables.Contains("Address") And Dts.Variables.Contains("Lat") And Dts.Variables.Contains("Long") Then
        Try
            ' Set a Bing Maps key before making a request

            Dim key As String = "Bing Key goes here"

            Dim geocodeRequest As New bing.geocode.GeocodeRequest

            Dim SearchAddress As String
            SearchAddress = Dts.Variables("Address").Value.ToString
            Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Address:", SearchAddress, "", 0, True)

            ' Set the credentials using a valid Bing Maps Key

            geocodeRequest.Credentials = New bing.geocode.Credentials()
            geocodeRequest.Credentials.ApplicationId = key

            ' Set the full address query

            geocodeRequest.Query = SearchAddress

            ' Set the options to only return high confidence results 
            Dim filters As bing.geocode.ConfidenceFilter() = New bing.geocode.ConfidenceFilter(0) {}
            filters(0) = New bing.geocode.ConfidenceFilter()
            filters(0).MinimumConfidence = bing.geocode.Confidence.High

            Dim geocodeOptions As New bing.geocode.GeocodeOptions()
            geocodeOptions.Filters = filters

            geocodeRequest.Options = geocodeOptions

            ' Make the geocode request
            Dim geocodeService As New bing.geocode.GeocodeServiceClient
            Dim geocodeResponse As bing.geocode.GeocodeResponse = geocodeService.Geocode(geocodeRequest)


            If geocodeResponse.Results.Length > 0 AndAlso geocodeResponse.Results(0).Locations.Length > 0 Then
                Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Lat:", geocodeResponse.Results(0).Locations(0).Latitude.ToString(), "", 0, False)
                Dts.Variables("Lat").Value = geocodeResponse.Results(0).Locations(0).Latitude
                Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Long:", geocodeResponse.Results(0).Locations(0).Longitude.ToString(), "", 0, True)
                Dts.Variables("Long").Value = geocodeResponse.Results(0).Locations(0).Longitude
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Dts.Events.FireError(-1, "Error:", ex.Message, "", 0)
            Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
        End Try
    Else
        Dts.Events.FireError(-1, "Error:", "Missing vairable in Task Component Definition.", "", 0)
    End If

End Sub


Enum ScriptResults
    Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success
    Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
End Enum
```

End Class

And this is my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <!-- This section defines the logging configuration for           My.Application.Log -->
        <source name="DefaultSource" switchName="DefaultSwitch">
            <listeners>
                <add name="FileLog"/>
                <!-- Uncomment the below section to write to the Application Event Log -->
                <!--<add name="EventLog"/>-->
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
        <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Information" />
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add name="FileLog"
             type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL"
             initializeData="FileLogWriter"/>
        <!-- Uncomment the below section and replace APPLICATION_NAME with the name of your application to write to the Application Event Log -->
        <!--<add name="EventLog" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="APPLICATION_NAME"/> -->
    </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="basicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocodeservice/GeocodeService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService"
            contract="basicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService" name="basicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that you need to check if your configuration file is setup properly

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:9999/"
            binding="yoursetting" bindingConfiguration="yoursetting"
            contract="yoursetting" name="yoursetting">
        </endpoint>
    </client>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Alternatively, it may be that the configuration needs to be restored. Which in that case you should remove the custom bindings from the configuration and rebuild the solution.

Comment: <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocodeservice/GeocodeService.svc"
                binding="BasicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService"
                contract="basicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService" />
        </client>

Comment: @Joey I would suggest you add this code into your question, to get more assistance.

Comment: Try removing the custom bindings from the configuration and rebuilding the project.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the old legacy Bing Maps SOAP services. These are nearing end of life and will be turned off at the end of June. Use the Bing Maps REST services instead which are faster, and have more features. The Bing Maps team created an open source toolkit for using the Bing Maps REST services in .NET. It's actually easier than using the SOAP services: https://github.com/Microsoft/BingMapsRESTToolkit/

That said, if you have a lot of data to geocode in your database on a regular basis, you may want to use the batch geocoding service that is in Bing Maps. Its a bit more work to setup but will be much faster for large data sets, will use less bandwidth. As an added bonus, if you license Bing Maps, the first 1M batch geocoded addresses a year are free customers. You can find documentation about this service here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701733.aspx

Comment: Is there a link that has it already done? I'm not sure how the 1st link you sent me works. I'm not a coder so a lot of that doesn't make sense.

Comment: On that page there is a link to the documentation for that toolkit. The documentation is pretty easy to follow: https://github.com/Microsoft/BingMapsRESTToolkit/wiki/Getting-Started